# How to substitute configSource for connection strings file during relase build?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to develop a pipeline for a .net web app using Azure tfs. I used the IIS Web Deploy template/utility already provided for such deployments. In the release pipeline, I am using XML variable transformation. But one issue I am facing is, that in the project, I have multiple .config files and I have included them in my `web.config` file as follows

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="None"/>  
  
  <appSettings file="None">
  </appSettings>
```

Based on the release for different environments, I perform variable substitution during the release. For example, a folder app_data contains `app_sttings_*.config` files and file variable does get replaced. But I am having an issue with the connection String file, I can not get `configSource` to change during release.

Am I doing this wrong or missing a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the **configSource** attribute cannot be replaced by the IIS Web App Deploy task. You can use the extension tool [Magic Chunks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeyzwezdin.magic-chunks) to replace the configSource value.

You can install Magic Chunks extension in your azure devops organization. And add **Config transformation** task before **IIS Web App Deploy task** to replace the configSource value.

First you need to define a variable (eg. configSource) to hold configSource value in the Release Pipeline variables section. Then configure the **Transformations** Section of  **Config transformation** task as below

```
{
  "configuration/connectionStrings/@configSource": "$(configSource)"
 }
```

There is another **Replace Tokens** task that can replace the configSource value. You can check it out [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

It said in the [IIS Web App Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops) that Variables defined in the Release Pipeline will be matched against the '**key**' or '**name**' entries in the appSettings, applicationSettings, and connectionStrings sections of the config files. Maybe that is the reason that configSource cannot be replaced by the IIS Web App Deploy task.

See [File transforms and variable substitution reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic) for more information.

Comment: I understand the key/name entries part, but it do work for appsettings where my varaible named file is replacing the file attribute for the appsettings tag

Comment: So, I am thinking may be I declared my connectionStrings wrong, but I checked it by hard coding the file name and replacement works. Its just that `configSource` is not getting replaced

Comment: I can reproduce the same issue. It seems that the variable substitution doesnot work the same way for `connectionStrings` element. You may need to use above Magic Chunks task as workaround.

Comment: I used your above mentioned procedure and it does get variable value, but still unable to replace/make changes to web.config at server side, do i need to point to web.config as well in JSON inline?

Comment: What do you mean by pointing to web.config as well in json inline.  To my understanding the web.config is specified in the `Path` field under `Source` section . Could you share your  configuration for magic chunks task.

Comment: So, I was able to, get my pipeline working using the tool you mentioned, but only after adding additional task for unzipping the artifacts, right now I am using the unzipped package for deployment purposes, but do you think there is any other cleaner solution, which won't require unzipping the artifacts?

Comment: If you donot want to unzip the artifacts. You can check out [File Transform task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops). But you need to create XML transformation file to transform the connectionStrings element in web.config file. See here for more information about [xml transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)